# Mahana Module for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, messaging

I am making an application in CodeIgniter and I need a Messaging Library Module there and I got a Library name Mahana. The Link is as follows.

https://github.com/jrmadsen67/Mahana-Messaging-library-for-CodeIgniter/tree/master/application

But I am unable to apply it as it has no controller and View portion. I am very new to CodeIgniter. Can any one provide me any link of total Mahana Librery or any other Messaging Library for CodeIgniter

Thank You

Comment: the link already has a tutorial how to use it. https://github.com/jrmadsen67/Mahana-Messaging-library-for-CodeIgniter

Comment: I have tried according to the instruction but it did not work and that is why I asked if anybody knows about the controller and View section.

Comment: @jmadsen given link is not working, please update

Comment: that blog has been taken down - https://github.com/jrmadsen67/Mahana-Messaging-library-for-CodeIgniter provides enough information to use, if the library still works 10 years later

Answer (score 4):

What's your problem ?
First you must create in the db, the tables from the dump mahana.sql,
and after use the variable that are in the configuration file *config/mahana.php* (**USER_TABLE_TABLENAME, USER_TABLE_ID,** and **USER_TABLE_USERNAME**) to integrate with a fast table access.
To use the library just put in your controller :

```
$this->load->library('mahana_messaging');
```

after that, when you want to get a message, create an object, and put in the method *get_message* the message id, and sender id, it will return a single message, including the status for specified user.

```
$mahana = new Mahana_messaging();
$msg = $mahana->get_message($msg_id, $sender_id);
```

U can also get the full thread of conversation using the method *get_full_thread*, it will return a entire thread conversation. To send a new internal message, that create a new thread, you must use the method *send_new_message* and pass the sender id, the recipient, the subject, the body, and finally the priority (this information, usually will be get from a web form, that you have created previously)

```
function send_new_message($sender_id, $recipients, $subject='', $body='', $priority=PRIORITY_NORMAL)
```

and so on ... there are other functions that permit you to reply a message, get partecipant...
Good work

Does this help at all????